# Yii simple relation understanding

Tags: yii, relational-database, relationship

I have a problem understanding relations.

I have these tables:

```
Modules
- name (pk)
- status_id (fk references status(id))

Status
- id (pk)
- name
```

So in Module I declare relations:

```
public function relations()
{
  return array(
    'status'=>array( self::HAS_ONE, 'Status', 'status_id' ),
  );
}
```

However this doesn't work, each status is NULL.

query executed by Yii:

```
SELECT `t`.`name` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`status_id` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`session_limit` AS `t0_c2`, `status`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `status`.`name` AS `t1_c1` FROM `ss_module` `t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `ss_module_status` `status` ON (`status`.`id`=`t`.`name`)

+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| t0_c0      | t0_c1 | t0_c2 | t1_c0 | t1_c1 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| digidoc    |     2 |     0 |  NULL | NULL  |
| docusearch |     1 |     2 |  NULL | NULL  |
| printbox   |     2 |     0 |  NULL | NULL  |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I have a problem understanding if the constants apply to the relationed model or the current model, example `Module HAS_ONE Status` or if should be `status BELONGS_TO a Module`.

Note that `BELONGS_TO` does work, so maybe I am answering myself but I would like some advice on how to better understand relations, because in the YII Guide examples, a `user HAS_ONE Profile`, so isn't it the same as `user HAS_ONE status`?

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the relation in both models incorrectly, then it has given the unexpected result. Currently what your code did is select all of records from parent table (`Status`) regardless whether it has children (`Module`) or not rather than versa.

While the FK was in `Module`, not `Status`, it should be

`Module` BELONG_TO `Status`

`Status` HAS_ONE `Module` (this is special case of `HAS_MANY` where `Status` has at most one `Module`)

I understood your confusing around, the answer that I think it would help you clear out your mind

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/181/relations-belongs_to-versus-has_one/

Comment: I dont understand the fact that STATUS has one Module, I meant that a MODULE must have a STATUS. But since the foreign key is in the Module table I think that makes it a CHILD and not a parent, right?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Currently what I saw from your relation, Module was child but has relation of a parent. Two relations were different then it would generate 2 SQL queries differently absolutely. I have attached the reference where explained what different between them in detail.